# cohomology of orbit space by a free group action

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, spectral-sequences

Let $G$ be a group. Let a principal $G$-bundle $G\to E\to B$. Then we have a fiber sequence  $G\to E\to B\to BG$.

Let $k$ be a field. 
Suppose $H^*(BG;k)$ and $H^*(E,k)$ are known. How to get $H^*(B;k)$?

The action of $\pi_1(BG)$ may not act trivially on $H^*(E;k)$.  Hence in Serre spectral sequence, local coefficients need to be used. However, local coefficients cohomology is unknown because we are not clear about the action of $\pi_1(BG)$ on $H^*(E,k)$. What should I do?

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on my algebraic topology, but doesn't the Leray-Hirsch theorem apply?